# Как ответить на сообщение пользователя после отправки сообщения в группу?

Tags: python, telebot

Имеется бот, работающий при помощи библиотеки telebot.

Мне нужно что бы когда пользователей писал в тех поддержку какое-нибудь сообщение,после оно отправляется в чат поддержки, это у меня получилось реализовать, но как ответить на его сообщение в группе с переносом ответа в основного бота?

Код техподдержки:

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == 'button_appeal_user')           # Обращение к техподдержке
def appeal_tp(message):
    global help_user_id
    help_user_id = message.from_user.id
    tp_help = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)  # Покупка цемента
    create_new_appeal_user = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Создать новое обращение', callback_data='appeal1')
    list_of_references = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Список обращений', callback_data='appeal2')
    tp_info_user = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Информация', callback_data='appeal3')
    tp_help.add(create_new_appeal_user, list_of_references, tp_info_user)
    bot.send_message(message.message.chat.id, text=f'''Если у вас возникли проблемы с 
заказом или вы хотите связаться с 
командой магазина нажмите кнопку 
Создать новое обращение''', reply_markup=tp_help)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda message: message.data == 'appeal1')
def client_request_tp(message):
    message_tp = bot.send_message(message.message.chat.id, text='Введите ваще обращение к техподдержке:')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message_tp, forward)

def forward(message):
    bot.forward_message(techsupport_message_user, message.chat.id, message.message_id)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def handle_text(m):
   # здесь если чат id равен id чата поддержки, то отправить сообщение пользователю который задал вопрос
   if int(m.chat.id) == int(techsupport_message_user):
      bot.send_message(help_user_id, m.text)
```